# In Flutter, when using the Google Maps Street View URL launcher, the functionality is working correctly on the emulator but not on real devices

Tags: flutter, dart

below code functions working correctly on the emulator, displaying the Street View of the specific location. However, on a real device, it seems to redirect to the device's current location on Google Maps, which is not the intended behavior. currently i am testing on android device

streetView()async {

```
String appleUrl = 'http://maps.apple.com/maps?layer=c&cbll=${socketPModel.latitude},${socketPModel.longitude}';
```

String googleUrl="http://www.google.com/maps?layer=c&cbll=${socketPModel.latitude},${socketPModel.longitude}";

```
Uri appleUri = Uri.parse(appleUrl);
Uri googleUri = Uri.parse(googleUrl);
if (Platform.isIOS) {
  if (await canLaunchUrl(appleUri)) {
    await launchUrl(appleUri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
  } else {
    if (await canLaunchUrl(googleUri)) {
      await launchUrl(googleUri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
    }
  }
} else {
  if (await canLaunchUrl(googleUri)) {
    await launchUrl(googleUri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Your question doesn't share enough information to share a specific answer. if your googlemap redirects to your current location you must have implemented functions to get current position using `geolocator ` and update the googlemaps camera position based on that positions `latitude` and `longitude`.